# convergence in distribution of transformation of random variable

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution

Sequence of r.v {Xn} s.t. every Xi has uniform distribution on (-1,1)

$$Y_{n} = X_{n}/n$$

show that Yn converges in distribution

so far I have
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n}\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X_{n}\leq ny)= (ny+1)/2$$
This tends to 0 as n tends to infinity

Is this correct and if so what is the random variable that Yn converges to?

Comment: First equation is correct; the second equation is technically correct but you have lost track of the cases that are involved, which is why the answer isn't obvious to you.

Comment: $|Y_n|\le\frac1n$ so $Y_n$ converges almost surely and in distribution towards a r.v. which is a.s. equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has a flaw. You have used $\Pr\{X\le u\}=\frac{u+1}{2}$ for all $u\in \Bbb R$, while this only holds for $u\in [-1,1]$. For this reason, for $y>0$ you should write
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr\{Y\le y\}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr\{X\le ny\}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr\{X\le 1\}=1
$$
and for $y<0$
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr\{Y\le y\}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr\{X\le ny\}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr\{X\le -1\}=0.
$$

Comment: That makes sense thank you. But what would that mean the distribution of the limit is?

Comment: Your welcome. The convergence in distribution technically means that the probability density function of a sequence of random variables is stabilizing to a deterministic density. In this case for example, it means that $X_n$s concentrate more around $0$ when $n\to\infty$.